# Flutter sdk installed and used on Macos is 3.3.10 but sdk too low to run project with requires SDK version >=3.0.0-68.0.dev <4.0.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

On my macos with M1 I am using flutter. It runs fine but when I create a project it does so with the environment sdk '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'. I am confused because I upgraded flutter and I can see in the doctor or with flutter --version that I have flutter 3.3.10.

This is annoying because I am trying to run a project that uses environment sdk '>=3.0.0-68.0.dev <4.0.0' but I cannot, I am getting this when running pub get:

"Because project requires SDK version >=3.0.0-68.0.dev <4.0.0, version solving failed."

I added flutter to the path variables, only have one path for flutter, and upgraded it but as I say, it seems to be up to date.

How come my flutter is up to date but seems to run on a past sdk version?

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

The environment sdk in pubspec.yaml refers to Dart sdk and not flutter. It seems the project I was trying to run was made with latest dart version in dev channel which is why I couldn't run it as I am on the latest stable channel.
Thanks Balaji

Comment: I assume you edited in the `environment` in `pubspec.yaml` file,  That's dart SDK version not flutter

Comment: Right, I did not edit it but a colleague created a project, and shared it with me. So his dart environment sdk seems to be 3+ but I see latest version is 2.18? Im confused? Maybe he is on another channel with higher version then!